# how to set a step for increment and decrement of spinbox value in python

Tags: python, tkinter, spinbox

i have a spinbox. i want to assign a step for it that value of spinbox Instead of changing by one unit, change by the value of this step. for example the value of "from_" option is 0 and the value of "to" option is 1. i want when user click on up button of spinbox the value of spinbox change to 0.001 and with second click the value change to 0.002 And so on. is there any option in spinbox to do it???

Comment: The spinbox has a documented `increment` option. Have you tried using it?

Comment: yes but i don't found any thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Spinbox` accepts an `increment` option:

> A floating-point value specifying the increment. When used with **from_** and **to**, the value in the widget will be adjusted by **increment** when a spin button is pressed (up adds the value, down subtracts the value).

```
sb = tk.Spinbox(root, from_=0, to=100, increment=.001)
```